# Pattern matching using python

Tags: python

In the code below how match the pattern after "answer" and "nonanswer" in the dictionary

```
opt_dict=(
    {'answer1':1,
     'answer14':1,
     'answer13':12,
     'answer11':6,
     'answer5':5,
     'nonanswer12':1,
     'nonanswer11':1,
     'nonanswer4':1,
     'nonanswer5':1,})
```

And

```
if opt_dict:
    for ii in opt_dict:
        logging.debug(ii)
        logging.debug(opt_dict[ii])
        if ii in "nonanswer":
            logging.debug(opt_dict[ii])
        elif ii in "answer":
            logging.debug("answer founddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd")
            logging.debug(opt_dict[ii])
        else:
            logging.debug("empty dict")
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say I've not much idea what you are asking. Please could you elaborate on your question? You do know that dictionaries are unordered, right? The general approach to asking questions is to show what your input is, what output you want and what you've tried so far to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't keep all your logging, but this should work:

```
if opt_dict:
    for key, value in opt_dict.items():
        if "nonanswer" in key:
            print "nonanswer", value
        elif "answer" in key:
            print "answer", value
        else:
            raise Exception( "invalid key" )
else:
    print "empty dict"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you have your `in` tests reversed. The data has the form `answer1`, which will never be in the literal `answer`. Try `"answer" in ii` instead.

To be more specific, you can use the [`startswith`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method, since all your data (at least in this example) actually starts with `answer` or `nonanswer`, and you might not want to match something of the form `34argleanswer`.